# How to place a JButton at a desired location in a JFrame using Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

I want to put a `JButton` at a particular **coordinate** in a `JFrame`. I used `setBounds()` for the `JPanel` (which I placed on the `JFrame`) and also `setBounds()` for the `JButton`. However, they don't seem to function as expected.

My Output:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Control extends JFrame {

    // JPanel
    JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
    // Buttons
    JButton btnAddFlight = new JButton("Add Flight");

    public Control() {
        // FlightInfo setbounds
        btnAddFlight.setBounds(60, 400, 220, 30);

        // JPanel bounds
        pnlButton.setBounds(800, 800, 200, 100);

        // Adding to JFrame
        pnlButton.add(btnAddFlight);
        add(pnlButton);

        // JFrame properties
        setSize(400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setTitle("Air Traffic Control");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();
    }
}
```

How do I place the `JButton` at coordinate (0, 0)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following line should be called before you add your component

```
pnlButton.setLayout(null);
```

Above will set your content panel to use absolute layout. This means you'd always have to set your component's bounds explicitly by using `setBounds` method.

In general I wouldn't recommend using absolute layout.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`child.setLocation(0, 0)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int,int)) on the button, and [`parent.setLayout(null)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager)). Instead of using setBounds(...) on the JFrame to size it, consider using just [`setSize(...)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize(int,int)) and letting the OS position the frame.

```
//JPanel
JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
//Buttons
JButton btnAddFlight = new JButton("Add Flight");

public Control() {

    //JFrame layout
    this.setLayout(null);

    //JPanel layout
    pnlButton.setLayout(null);

    //Adding to JFrame
    pnlButton.add(btnAddFlight);
    add(pnlButton);

    // postioning
    pnlButton.setLocation(0,0);
```

Comment: The Java tutorial recommends `setBounds`.  `setLocation` just delegates to `setBounds` anyway.

Comment: @Mark_Peters True, though I was (perhaps wrongly) assuming that in asking to set the position, like most apps, the JButton was to be sized automatically. `setLocation` does invoke `setBounds`, but it uses the components current width and height, letting it size naturally based on contents. Typical, but you're right, not always what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out. For the button do `.setBounds(0, 0, 220, 30)`
The `.setBounds` layout has following parameters - (int x, int y, int width, int height)

Answer (score 2):

Define somewhere the consts :

```
private static final int BUTTON_LOCATION_X = 300;  // location x 
private static final int BUTTON_LOCATION_Y = 50;   // location y 
private static final int BUTTON_SIZE_X = 140;      // size height
private static final int BUTTON_SIZE_Y = 50;       // size width
```

and then below :

```
                JButton startButton = new JButton("Click Me To Start!");
                // startButton.setBounds(300, 50,140, 50 );
                startButton.setBounds(BUTTON_LOCATION_X
                                    , BUTTON_LOCATION_Y,
                                      BUTTON_SIZE_X, 
                                      BUTTON_SIZE_Y );
                contentPane.add(startButton);
```

where `contentPane` is the `Container`  object that holds the entire frame :

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Some name goes here");
 Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
```

I hope this helps , works great for me ...

Answer (score 2):

You should set layout first by syntax `pnlButton.setLayout()`, and then choose the most suitable layout which u want. Ex: `pnlButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));`. And then, take that JButton into JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

I created the following GUI.

[image: Air Traffic Control]

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I used a `JFrame`.  I did not extend a `JFrame`.  This is referred to as composition over inheritance.  The only reason you should extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is if you intend to override one or more of the class methods.

A `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  I placed the `JPanel` in the center of the `JFrame`.

I created a `JPanel` to place in the `JFrame`.  I used a `FlowLayout` to place the `JButton` in the center of the top of the `JPanel`.  If you want the `JButton` to be somewhere else, you can adjust the values of the empty border to place the `JButton` where you want.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AirTrafficControl implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AirTrafficControl());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Air Traffic Control");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        
        JButton btnAddFlight = new JButton("Add Flight");
        panel.add(btnAddFlight);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remember your JPanel size height and size width, then observe: JButton coordinates is (xo, yo, x length , y length). If your window is 800x600, you just need to write:

```
JButton.setBounds(0, 500, 100, 100);
```

You just need to use a coordinate gap to represent the button, and know where the window ends and where the window begins.