# How to place a JButton at a specific x - y point on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

**GENERAL CODE: ISSUES BELOW WILL REFERENCE CERTAIN CLASSES**

```
public class Board extends JPanel { 

public Board() {
    BoardMethods a = new BoardMethods();//BoardMethods handles logic
    a.printBoard(getBoard());//irrelevant to question, helps determine winner
    JPanel panelLORDY = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    //JButton alphaButton = new JButton("Hi");
    //alphaButton.setBounds(213,131,100,100);
    //add(alphaButton);
}

public int[][] getBoard(){
    return boardEvalMatrix;
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1456, 916);
    Graphics2D newG = (Graphics2D) g;
    newG.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15));
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)//rows for board --- rowHeight is 127
        g.drawRect(128, 68 + (a*127), 1200, 127);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    newG.setStroke(new BasicStroke(8));
    for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)//columns for board --- columnWidth is 171
        g.drawRect(128 + (a*171), 68, 171, 764);        
    for(int a = 0; a < 6; a++)//give rows black line in middle
        g.drawRect(128, 68 + (a*127), 1200, 127);
    //g.drawString("H", 213, 131); center point     
    //g.drawLine(50,0, 1456, 916); //width 1456 length 916 - school computer monitors
    JButton alphaButton = new JButton("Hi");
    alphaButton.setBounds(213,131,100,100);
    bored.add(alphaButton);

}
}


public class gameBoard extends JPanel {

private Board bored;
private RoundButton[][] buttonArray;//holds all roundButtons on board
private JPanel resetPanel, quitPanel;

public gameBoard() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    buttonArray = new RoundButton[6][7];
    for(int a = 0; a < buttonArray.length; a++)
        for(int b = 0; b < buttonArray[0].length; b++)


    bored = new Board();
    add(bored, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    resetPanel = new JPanel();
    resetPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(resetPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    quitPanel = new JPanel();
    quitPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(quitPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new resetListener());
    resetPanel.add(resetButton);//resets board
    JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
    quitButton.addActionListener(new quitListener());
    quitPanel.add(quitButton);

    //JButton alphaButton = new JButton("Hi");
    //alphaButton.setBounds(213,131,100,100);
    //bored.add(alphaButton);


}
}
```

**ISSUE 1:**

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195666/how-to-place-a-jbutton-at-a-desired-location-in-a-jframe-using-java) regarding how to place a `JButton` at a certain location, however, I have circular appearing `JButton`s and I need the `JButton` to be centered on a certain point, in this case, `213,131`. I am using the `setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)` method to place the `JButton`. Is there a way to have the `JButton` center itself on the coordinate mentioned above, or do I have to play with the numbers to get it where I want? This line can be found in both classes above, as I was testing something and found an issue described in **ISSUE 2**.

```
JButton alphaButton = new JButton("Hi");
alphaButton.setBounds(213,131,100,100);
add(alphaButton);
```

**ISSUE 2:**

If you look at the class `Board`, in the `paintComponent` method I use the `setBounds()` method to place my `JButton`. This works and places a button with what I believe are the correct dimensions on the `JPanel` when the `paintComponent()` method is called with the top left corner in the correct location. However, when the screen is refreshed, `paintComponent()` is again called and the number of buttons continues to increase, fun to mess with but not what I want. However, when I move the `setBounds` method and `alphaButton` anywhere outside of `Board`'s `paintComponent()` method, that is, putting it into the class that `Board` is painted on, inside the `Board` constructor, the `JButton` propagation issue ceases, however, the `JButton` no longer places itself at the correct coordinate point and loses the dimensions that I gave it. How do I fix this?

**P.S.** You will see the `setBounds` method several times. In the real code, the `setBounds` method and the `JButton` calling it only exist in one class at a time, I entered it here multiple times to show you where I placed it.

Comment: reason for downvote? question is explict, demonstrates effort, and a concise code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `setBounds()`, stick to a layout manager.

`FlowLayout` *will* automatically center your component. Even better is to use `BorderLayout`, and set to the `CENTER`.

Comment: JButton alphaButton = new JButton("Hi");
  bored.add(alphaButton);
  alphaButton.setBounds(213,131,100,100); I did this, but no change. pops up above the game board and real tiny and is not square-ular

Comment: A better solution for issue 2 would be to not handle calculations in the `paintComponent` method, as this method will be called under a wide variety of common situations.

Comment: @VinceEmigh there are no calculations besides the one for drawing the line because I was too lazy to use my calculator so I just had java handle it

Comment: Vince didn't mean arithmatic, but rather any statement he/she is referring to.

Comment: @MouseEvent so then what is vince reffing?